# Skype and qjackctl

Tags: 14.04, skype, ubuntu-studio

I have Ubuntu Studio 14.04 and qjackctl with guitarx works just fine, but for some reason I can't get qjackctl to function when skype is running. The moment I am in a skype call it's like qjackctl just doesnt' connect to anything anymore. But the program window stays up. Things I have tried:

-having qjackctl and guitarx up and running, tested and it's working. Then started a skype call and suddenly no sound from guitar anymore.

-starting skype call first then starting qjackctl and guitarx but guitarx says jackd isn't running (that window comes up that asks what you want to do). I have tried telling guitarx to start it but it says it couldn't be started and I have tried ignoring it sense qjackctl was actually already up and running.

Not sure what is going on but I would like to have this working so I can do sessions over skype like lessons and show friends what I have came up with. I don't need to send my guitarx signal through skype, i can just put that through my speakers or monitors and let the skype microphone pick that up. So all I need is qjackctl to function properly with skype in a call. Anyone have a clue?